# How to prove point A belongs to line t?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I'm stuck at trying to prove that any point $A$ will belong to line $t$ if and only if segments $AB=AC$, where $B$ and $C$ are symmetrical points to the line $t$ and $M$ is the midpoint of segment $BC$.

I started of with this graph

[image]

And modified it like so

[image]

From here I've managed to deduce that $\triangle{ABM}$ and $\triangle{ACM}$ are equal by using one attribute of equal triangles. But by this point I'm not sure this is even useful. What am I missing, how do you prove $A$ belongs to $t$ under these circumstances?

Comment: Sorry for the OT. What program do you use to draw the images? Thanks and sorry.

Comment: @FernandoPelliccioni Hey! I used a LaTeX editor,  but I don't remember exactly which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider any point $A$ that is equidistant from both $B$ and $C$. Draw a perpendicular from $A$ on BC and let it be $M'$. Consider the triangles $ABM'$ and $ACM'$, Note that in AM' is the common side of these two triangles, and $AC=AB$ is our assumption, as both of these triangles are right-angled ones, they must be congruent by our assumption, however in that case $BM'=CM'$, this implies that $M=M'$. This implies $A$ is on the line $t$.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the apostrophe after a point notation. could you please explain how that works?

Comment: Nothing special, I just tried to mean that $M'$ is a point (I gave that apostrophe to distinguish it from $M$)

Answer (score 1):

Line t can be defined as a set of points whose distance from B and C are equal.

If we put the set T, A$\in$T if and only if A belongs to the line t.

So if we assume $AB \ne AC$, then A $\notin$T,

therefore A belongs to the line t if and only if AB=AC.